# has_one relation collection_select undefined method `department_id' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have model schema:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :department
end
class Department
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :order
end
```

Order form look like this:

```
<%= form_for @order, :html => {} do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:department_id, Department.all, :id,:name) %>
  <%= f.submit nil %>
<% end %>
```

Submit throws this error message:

```
undefined method `department_id' for #<Order:0x007f993861e0f8>
```

I really dont know why. Any idea? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should change the model definitions.
The `belongs_to` definition requires a corresponding id value in the model. The `has_one` does not, since it relies on the counterpart.

So, you should setup your models inverting the `has_one` and `belongs_to` calls:

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :department
end
class Department
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_one :order
end
```

I also fear that a `Department` should have more than one order associated. In this case you can simply delete the `has_one :order` statement.

Now, to make everything work you must be sure that a `department_id` field exists in the `Order` model. I do not know the Mongoid world, but for an usual database you'd do something like this

```
rails g migration AddDepartmentIdToOrders department_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

You should be fine, then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are going in the opposite direction from the storage for the relation.
The storage for the relation from Order to Department is actually stored
as the foreign key order_id on Department, not department_id on Order.
You can verify this by inspecting objects for your models after you have set a relationship.
If you want to use collection_select, you need to go in the other direction to use the foreign key.
The example below shows how to go in the forward direction from parent to child.
Hope that it helps you to advance.

app/controllers/demo_controller.rb

```
class DemoController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @order = Order.first
    render :show
  end
end
```

app/views/demo/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Demo#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/demo/show.html.erb</p>

<%= form_for @order, url: {action: "show"}, :html => {} do |order_form| %>
    <%= order_form.text_field :date %>
    <%= fields_for @order.department do |order_department_form| %>
        <%= order_department_form.text_field :name %>
    <% end %>
    <%= order_form.submit nil %>
<% end %>
```

test/functional/demo_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class DemoControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  def setup
    Order.delete_all
    Department.delete_all
    puts
  end
  test "0. mongoid version" do
    puts "Mongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
  end
  test "should get show" do
    order = Order.create(date: Time.now)
    department = Department.create(name: 'Development')
    order.department = department
    assert_equal 1, Order.count
    assert_equal 1, Department.count
    get :show
    assert_response :success
    #puts @response.body
  end
end
```